# typescript interface dynamic param does not compile without any

Tags: typescript

I have a type as follows, where if name is anything OTHER THAN "filter" the type is "AggrEntry" and "filter" is of type "Aggr".

```
export interface Aggr {
    [name: string]: AggrEntry;
    filter?: Aggr;
}
```

However the ts code won't compile unless I change `[name: string]: AggrEntry;` to `[name: string]: any;`.

The error is

```
[ts] Property 'filter' of type 'ResponseAggregation' is not assignable to string index type 'ResponseAggregationEntry'.
```

Logically I am guessing typescript tries to assign `[name: string]` to filter since filter itself can get mapped to `[name: string]`. So how would I structure my interface so that the ts compiler knows that "name" won't ever be "filter" then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you define an indexer all properties must conform to the return type of the interface. You could do the following:

```
export interface Aggr {
    [name: string]: AggrEntry |Aggr;
    filter?: Aggr;
}
```

This is obviously not ideal as this allows other fields except `filter` to be of type `Aggr`.

Another option is to use a `type` definition instead of an interface, and use a intersection type:

```
export type Aggr  = {
    [name: string]: AggrEntry;
} & {
    filter?: Aggr;
}

let test : Aggr;
let foo = test.foo // foo is AggrEntry
test.filter // works, is of type Aggr
```

While we can access object fields as expected, creating an object of this type is a bit trickier. Creating an object literal with the `filter` field will yield a similar error to your original. We can use Object.assign to create an instance of the type using object literals:

```
let test : Aggr = Object.assign({
    foo: new AggrEntry()
}, {
    filter: {
        bar: new AggrEntry()
    }
});
```

Or we can create a dedicated function to help with creation, that uses `Object.assign`:

```
function createAggr(dynamicPart: {
    [name: string]: AggrEntry;
}, staticPart?: {
    filter?: Aggr;
}) {
    return Object.assign(dynamicPart, staticPart);
}

let test : Aggr = createAggr({
    foo: new AggrEntry()
}, {
    filter: {
        bar: new AggrEntry()
    }
});
```

Comment: That intersection type is strange.  As you say, it behaves more or less as expected when you access fields, but can you count on that behavior?  It's arguably a bug, since `(T & U)['prop']` should by rights be the same as `T['prop'] & U['prop']`.  Not that there's a great alternative answer.  

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, there isn't a great way to emulate these types in Typescript, this solution is I close as I got and for now it works …