# TypeScript Interface With Known and Unknown Keys Not Using `any`

Tags: typescript

I need an interface to describe a data structure that always contains a function, but can contain any number of properties, which all have a value of string. I know something like this works in theory:

```
declare interface Profile {
    getXml: () => string;
    [key: string]: string | Function;
}
```

However, that interface isn't 100% accurate and makes using objects of that type more difficult because I can't assign a property of that interface to a string without checking or casting first.

Is there any way that I can specify an interface have a certain set of known keys with their own unique value types and then have a 'catch-all' for everything else that might be on the object? The solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260414/typescript-interface-for-objects-with-some-known-and-some-unknown-property-names) requires the use of `any`, which is worse than what I have.

Please see [this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20interface%20Profile%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20Function%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20incomingProfile%3A%20Profile%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20'xml'%3B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20data1%3A%20'data1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20data2%3A%20'data2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20otherData%3A%20'otherData'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20don't%20want%20to%20have%20to%20cast%20or%20guard%20to%20get%20this%20to%20work%0D%0Avar%20incomingData%3A%20string%20%3D%20incomingProfile%5B'data1'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20won't%20work%20because%20a%20Function%20isn't%20of%20type%20string%20%0D%0Adeclare%20interface%20Profile2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20incomingProfile2%3A%20Profile2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20'xml'%3B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20data1%3A%20'data1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20data2%3A%20'data2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20otherData%3A%20'otherData'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A) to see why some options that have been proposed don't work.

Please see [this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20interface%20Profile%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20Function%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20incomingProfile%3A%20Profile%20%3D%20%3CProfile%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20don't%20want%20to%20have%20to%20cast%20or%20guard%20to%20get%20this%20to%20work%0D%0Avar%20incomingData%3A%20string%20%3D%20incomingProfile%5B'data1'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20won't%20work%20because%20a%20Function%20isn't%20of%20type%20string%20%0D%0Adeclare%20interface%20Profile2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20incomingProfile2%3A%20Profile2%20%3D%20%3CProfile2%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Works!%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Profile3%20%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getXml%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20incomingProfile3%3A%20Profile3%20%3D%20%3CProfile3%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20incomingData3%3A%20string%20%3D%20incomingProfile3%5B'data1'%5D%0D%0Avar%20inccomingXml3%3A%20string%20%3D%20incomingProfile3.getXml()%3B) to see an options that does work thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630461/typescript-interface-dynamic-param-does-not-compile-without-any).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript interface dynamic param does not compile without any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630461/typescript-interface-dynamic-param-does-not-compile-without-any)

Comment: It's basically the same problem as in the referenced question, in your case type type would be `type Profile = {
    getXml: () => string;  } & {
    [key: string]: string;
}` but the discussion applies

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, The answer you linked to helped me to find what works. I wish that OP had marked that answer as correct. If you post it here, or a link to it, I'll gladly do so myself.

Comment: They accepted the answer, I had just answered  it that day, it was abit much to give the same answer again on the same day, 10x anyway :)