# How to define type safe collections with dynamic keys in Typescript and still have intellisense support

Tags: typescript, intellisense, type-safety

I am using interfaces to define type safe objects in Typescript, and to provide easy to maintain code structure. However, there are some cases where the intellisense is broken.

What should be the best approach when the keys are unknown and still want to have code completion?

Here is a simple example to show what I mean:

```
interface IObject {
  name: string,
  value: number
};

// here is the type safe collection interface
interface ICollection {
  [key: string]: IObject
};

// ...

// here is the type safe collection
let collection: ICollection = {
  a: {
    name: "a",
    value: 1
  },
  b: {
    name: "b",
    value: 2
  }
};

// here is the type unsafe collection
let collection2 = {
  a: {
    name: "a",
    value: 1
  },
  b: {
    name: "b",
    value: 2
  },
  c: {
    key: 1,
    status: true
  }
};

// ...

console.log(collection2.a.value); // this works ok, but it's not type safe
console.log(collection.a.value); // this is type safe, but there is no more intellisense support
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an answer described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630741/11005213

Something along these lines:

```js
interface IObject {
  name: string;
  value: number;
};

interface IUnsafeObject extends Partial<IObject> {
  // if you know the type you can narrow it down here
  // e.g. [key: string]: boolean | number
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface ICollection<TType> {
  [key: string]: TType
};

let collection: ICollection<IObject> = {
  a: { name: "a", value: 1 },
  b: { name: "b", value: 2 }
};

let collection2 : ICollection<IUnsafeObject> = {
  a: { name: "a", value: 1 },
  b: { name: "b", value: 2 },
  c: { key: 1, status: true }
};
```

You can also achieve the same thing with types instead of interfaces:

```js
type MyObject = {
  name: string,
  value: number
};

type MyUnsafeObject = { [key: string]: any } & Partial<MyObject>;
```

See also:
Partial - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt
Generics - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Yes, these are valid for defining unsafe objects, but don't solve the problem with intellisense. If you then type collection, it doesn't auto complete with a, b, c. Whereas, if no interface is assigned, intellisense works (but it's no longer type safe)